# How to query for and delete embedded objects in an array field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to run an update command that finds an object in an array field for all documents and then pulls it from that array field for all documents. I have tried the below commands, which do not return any documents (nMatched: 0).

```
db.users.update({"likedQuizzes.quiz": { $elemMatch: quizObj}},{$pull: {"likedQuizzes.quiz": quizObj }});
db.users.update({"likedQuizzes": { $elemMatch: quizObj}},{$pull: {"likedQuizzes": quizObj }});
```

In the above cases `quizObj = {"title" : "2 Purple", "author" : "purple-tester1"}`

Here is a sample document from the 'users' collection:

```
{

"_id" : ObjectId("581114330de9ac0c1445cdd6"),
"user" : "test-username1",  
"likedQuizzes" : [
        {
            "quiz" : {
                "title" : "2 Purple",
                "author" : "purple-tester1"
            },
            "date" : ISODate("2016-10-26T20:39:02.695Z")
        },
        {
            "quiz" : {
                "title" : "1 Purple",
                "author" : "purple-tester1"
            },
            "date" : ISODate("2016-10-26T20:39:12.374Z")
        },
        {
            "quiz" : {
                "title" : "4 Green",
                "author" : "green-tester1"
            },
            "date" : ISODate("2016-10-26T20:39:25.304Z")
        },
        {
            "quiz" : {
                "title" : "3 Green",
                "author" : "green-tester1"
            },
            "date" : ISODate("2016-10-26T20:39:37.326Z")
        },
        {
            "quiz" : {
                "title" : "2 Green",
                "author" : "green-tester1"
            },
            "date" : ISODate("2016-10-26T20:40:12.964Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Said another way, I am simply trying to find if a quiz is in a users' "likedQuizzes" array, and if it is, delete it from that array (along with the "date" that it was liked).

After some researching it looks like this might not be possible, but I wanted to ask anyway because I *think* my schema might be different enough from the examples that came up in my research. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could restructure your document to be of this structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581114330de9ac0c1445cdd6"),
    "user" : "test-username1",
    "likedQuizzes" : [
        {
            "title" : "2 Purple",
            "author" : "purple-tester1",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-10-26T20:39:02.695Z")
        },
        {
            "title" : "1 Purple",
            "author" : "purple-tester1",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-10-26T20:39:12.374Z")
        },
        {
            "title" : "4 Green",
            "author" : "green-tester1",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-10-26T20:39:25.304Z")
        },
        {
            "title" : "3 Green",
            "author" : "green-tester1",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-10-26T20:39:37.326Z")
        },
        {
            "title" : "2 Green",
            "author" : "green-tester1",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-10-26T20:40:12.964Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

After that... if you run the following command:

```
db.users.update(
    {
        "likedQuizzes": { 
            $elemMatch: {
                "title" : "2 Purple", 
                "author" : "purple-tester1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $pull: { 
            "likedQuizzes": { 
                "title": "2 Purple",
                "author": "purple-tester1"
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Your $pull will now work.  $pull doesn't seem to play nicely with $elemMatch

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you are trying to do is to pass the whole quiz object to the `$elemMatch` and expecting it to return the match documents from MongoDB, but it won't work that way.

You have to modify your query a bit like

```
{"likedQuizzes.quiz.title": { $elemMatch: quizObj.title}
```

Reason : mongodb won't do the field by field compare for you. You should have a unique identifier based on which you can query.

Even in the RDBMS world you cannot do this.

What you are trying to do is something like:

```
quizObj q;
q.title = "2 Purple";
q.author = "purple-tester1";

select * from quizTable where row = q.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try

```
db.users.update({"likedQuizzes": { $elemMatch: {"quiz.title" : "2 Purple", "quiz.author" : "purple-tester1"}}},
{$pull: {"likedQuizzes": {"quiz" : {"title" : "2 Purple", "author" : "purple-tester1"}}}})
```

What you can do is use your `quizObj = {"quiz.title" : "2 Purple", "quiz.author" : "purple-tester1"}`

Hope it helps.
And then below query

```
db.users.update({"likedQuizzes": { $elemMatch: quizObj }},{$pull: {"likedQuizzes": quizObj }})
```